# Есть ли библиотека для решения систем нелинейных уравнений для Java/Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, поиск-библиотек, scipy

Нужно решить системы нелинейных уравнений на Java или Kotlin. И встал вопрос, а есть ли что-то похожее на `fsolve` из `scipy.optimize` для этих языков? Может кто знает и может подсказать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Была найдена библиотека [DasOptimization](https://github.com/aniltrkkn/DasOptimization), которая как раз предназначена для решения систем нелинейных уравнений